# After replacing .net dll in IIS web site bin folder it get slower

Tags: .net, iis, dll

I've a .net dll class library which is used by this web site in IIS. The code base is so vast that; it cannot be run F5 in Visual Studio for debugging, so I've to modify this class library and compile it to dll and replace it in IIS web site bin (yes, it's a tedious job) for debugging.

Now, the problem; the page which accesses this dll gets slower time to time. Now, its quiet slow, How to make it faster?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you built the .dll in RELEASE Mode..

Comment: No, in debug mode..but this in the only way I can debug this application, in Release it's not possible.